# Insert data to database when click checkout button

Tags: php, e-commerce

Currently I'm trying to develop online shopping website. I'm having difficulties in insert data to database table when I click add to cart button the data did not insert. Can anybody who have expertise tell me where is the problem? Below are my code.

```
$sqlSelectProdCat1 = mysql_query("select * from tblproduct where prod_cat = 'Hall Package'") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($sqlSelectProdCat1) >= 1){
    $displayProdCat .= '<h2></h2>';
    while($getProdInfo1 = mysql_fetch_array($sqlSelectProdCat1)){
        $prodNo = $getProdInfo1["prod_no"];
        $prodId = $getProdInfo1["pro_id"];
        $prodName = $getProdInfo1["prod_name"];
        $prodDescri = $getProdInfo1["prod_descri"];
        $hallservice= $getProdInfo1["hall_service"];
        $prodPrice = $getProdInfo1["prod_price"];
        $displayProdCat .= '<form  method="post" action="choosepackage.php" /><div class="team-row"><div class="col-md-9 w3ls-team-grids" >
                        <div class="grid_3 grid_5 wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay=".5s">
                        <h5>'.$prodName.'</h5>
                        <h4>RM'.$prodPrice.'</h4>
                        <h4>(Minimum pax:1000)</h4>
                        <p>'.$prodDescri.'</p>

                    </br>
                    <h6>Service include:</h6>
                    <p><strong>'.$hallservice.'</strong></p>

                    <h1>
                        <a href="cart.php?prodid='.$prodId.'"  ><span class="label label-danger">Add to Cart</span></a>
                    </h1>
                      <button type="submit" name="order" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>&nbsp;Add</button>
                       <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
                       <input type="submit" name="continue" class="button-w3layouts hvr-rectangle-out">
                    </div>
                    </div></form>';



        if(++$prodCatCtr == 4)
            break;

    }

    <?php

                    if (isset($_POST['continue'])) {
                   $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

                   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
                    if (!$con){
                        die("Can not connect:" . mysql_error());
                    }

                    mysqli_select_db($con,"mywedding");

                    mysqli_query($con,"insert into tblorderitem (customerid,productid,productname,productimage,productprice,productquantity,orderstatus) values('$session1','$prodId','$prodName','$prodNo','$prodPrice','$quantity',Pending')");

                    echo "done";
                    }
                    ?>

}
```

Comment: It is redirecting to **cart.php**. In which page, you are inserting?

Comment: You also have no error checking on that insert statement (which also appears to be missing a `'`)

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** _mysql_*-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are **wide open to** [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: You have to keep watching to the strings you insert into your database. Because a string have to marked with ' in your statement. You got an error message when you try to insert it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest first you split this in multiple files. and then take a good look at your form since its not passing along any information about the product you want to add to the cart.

Also it would be wiser to just insert a productId into tblorderitem instead of the entire product with all its data.